# WSO2 ESB - Jira Connector - updateIssue

Tags: wso2, jira, esb, connector

I'm trying to use the the JIRA connector in WSO2 ESB and I have no idea how to use the **updateIssue** module, no matter what I put in the **issueFields** property I always get the

```
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed
```

exception when I deploy it and execute. Sadly, there is no detailed example of how to use this module in the documentation. Thanks in advance.

[image: WSO2 Developer Studio]

Answer (score 0):

This is how Updating an issue  working in ESB Connector.So check issueIdOrKey is correct or not and check the format of issueFields also it will be JSON string.

```
<jira.updateIssue>
     <issueIdOrKey>ESBJAVA-2095</issueIdOrKey>
     <issueFields>{$ctx:issueFields}</issueFields>
</jira.updateIssue>
```

To update an issue, use jira.updateIssue, specify the issue ID, and attach the JSON representation of the issue to the request as the payload. You use a similar approach as when creating an issue, but use the update parameter instead of fields when you're doing more than simply setting a new field. For example, if you wanted to change the description and add and remove labels, you could use the update parameter as follows:

```
{
    "update": {
        "description": [
            {
                "set": "We need to update the license agreement file before shipping the 2.0 release. Please get from John Smith in the legal department."
            }
        ],
        "labels": [
            {
                "add": "triaged"
            },
            {
                "remove": "blocker"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you just need to set the value of fields, you can use the fields parameter instead, which is the equivalent of using set with the update parameter. See Creating an issue for an example of using the fields parameter.

You can either set the explicit field values or use an operation to change the field value. The fields that can be updated, in either the fields parameter or the update parameter, can be determined using the /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/editmeta resource. If a field is not configured to appear on the edit screen, it will not be in the editmeta, and a field validation error will occur if it is submitted.
Properties

```
issueIdOrKey: Identifies the issue to update. This can be an issue ID, or an issue key. If the issue cannot be found via an exact match, JIRA will also look for the issue in a case-insensitive way, or by looking to see if the issue was moved.
```

Related JIRA API

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/6.1.html#d2e1209